# Como colocar máscara em tabela com angular?

Tags: angularjs, mask

Como colocar máscara monetária em uma tabela ? Para os inputs utilizei a diretiva **ui-money-mask**, mas preciso colocar em uma célula de tabela.

`<td>{{item.valor}}</td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `filter` [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency)

Para mostrar no formato real (R$) você tem duas opções, utilizando o `Angular Locale`, veja [Usando Locale no AngularJS](http://imasters.com.br/front-end/javascript/serie-angularjs-usando-locale-angularjs-parte-04/?trace=1519021197&source=single)

```html
<!--Utilizando o Angular Locale-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="valor='85.41'">
  <input ng-model="valor" />
  <!--Máscara default utilizando o locale - (R$xx,xx).-->
  <p>{{valor | currency}}</p>
  <!--Você pode alterar o símbolo da moeda como preferir - (R$ xx,xx).-->
  <p>{{valor | currency:'R$ '}}</p>
</div>
```

Ou você pode informar um identificador no filtro, dessa maneira, apenas irá mostrar o identificador que você informar (R$ por exemplo), porém, dessa maneira (sem utilizar o locale) o separador de decimais será o padrão inglês com um ponto e não uma vírgula como no formato brasileiro.

```html
<!--Sem o Angular locale-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app ng-init="valor='85.41'">
  <input ng-model="valor" />
  <!--Máscara Default sem o locale - ($xx.xx).-->
  <p>{{ valor | currency }}</p>
  <!--Máscara formatada sem o locale - (R$xx.xx).-->
  <p>{{ valor | currency: 'R$' }}
</div>
```

Comment: Isso já me ajuda, mas para imprimir no formato R$ xxx,xx, como faço ? No caso, utilizando vírgula em vez de ponto ?

Comment: O arquivo `angular-locale` é um JSON, você pode localizar no arquivo onde define a moeda e adicionar um espaço `R$ ` ou adicionar a máscara com o espaço diretamente no `filter:currency`

Comment: Bacana, valeu a ajuda.